# Introductory Ruby Threading Issue

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've been learning Ruby for the past few days, and I've run into a few issues concerning the implementation of threads. I've programmed in other languages before (mainly Java and C), and I still couldn't figure out what the issue is. I'm running ruby 2.1.2p95 on Ubuntu Server 14.10. The code in question is from Mr. Neighborly's Humble Little Ruby Book:

```
mate = Thread.new do
  puts "Ahoy! Can I be dropping the anchor sir?"
  Thread.stop
  puts "Aye sir, dropping anchor!"
end

Thread.pass

puts "CAPTAIN: Aye, laddy!"

mate.run
mate.join
```

The output should be:

```
Ahoy! Can I be dropping the anchor sir?
CAPTAIN: Aye, laddy!
Aye sir, dropping anchor!
```

But instead, I'm receiving the following join and deadlock error:

```
CAPTAIN: Aye, laddy!
Ahoy! Can I be dropping the anchor sir?
ex2.rb:12:in `join': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
    from ex2.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I've run into errors with other threading examples from other resources as well, and have tried running the examples on other Ubuntu machines as well as trying Ruby 2.2. Is there a blatant concept that I'm missing out on? Has something changed in recent revisions of Ruby that would deem the examples out-of-date? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code works as expected for me, using Ruby 2.0.0 on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.2.0 on OS X Yosemite and I'm getting the error. I'm guessing this is a bug.

Comment: I've found that this code causes the error to happen more reliably for me: `Thread.new { Thread.stop }.join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has something changed in recent revisions of Ruby that would deem the examples out-of-date?

Yes. It looks like this book was [written for Ruby 1.8](http://www.humblelittlerubybook.com/book/html/chapter0.html), which used [*green* threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads). Ruby 1.9 onwards uses *native* threads (where the threads are scheduled by the OS).

Compare the documentation for the [`Thread.pass` method in Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Thread.html#method-c-pass):

> Invokes the thread scheduler to pass execution to another thread.

In Ruby 2.1.2 (the version you are using), [this methods documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html#method-c-pass) looks like this:

> Give the thread scheduler a hint to pass execution to another thread. A running thread may or may not switch, it depends on OS and processor.

So in current versions the scheduling is not deterministic in the way it was in Ruby 1.8.7, the OS is free to ignore the call to `Thread.pass` and run the main thread first, which causes the problems.

Running this script on my machine (Mac OS 10.9, Ruby 2.2.0) I get both results, sometimes it works and I see:

```
Ahoy! Can I be dropping the anchor sir?
CAPTAIN: Aye, laddy!
Aye sir, dropping anchor!
```

Other times it fails with:

```
CAPTAIN: Aye, laddy!
Ahoy! Can I be dropping the anchor sir?
capt-thread.rb:12:in `join': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
    from capt-thread.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This error still confuses me, because even if `Thread.pass` doesn't have an effect, there still isn't a deadlock, right? I would have expected to simply see the output in the wrong order.

Comment: @Adrian The error occurs because you are trying to `join` (that is wait for it to finish) a thread that has been stopped. It can never finish, and Ruby detects this and raises an exception. I think the `Deadlock?` in the error message is just a suggestion of what might have happened. In this case it’s not really a deadlock, but is a bit like one as the `mate` thread is waiting for the main thread to run it, and the main thread thinks it already has.

Comment: I agree with @Adrian. I feel like even if Thread.pass doesn't force the main thread to pass execution time to another thread, the use of Thread.join would at least allow all threads to complete their execution. 
Edit: Just saw your response to Adrian, let me fiddle with the example a little bit.

Comment: Actually I’ve just re-read the error message, it’s saying there are no live threads left – one is stopped, one is waiting on the stopped one. If there were any other threads in the program it would continue running, but the final message would not appear (unless the `mate` thread was started again).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Thread.pass can't be used completely reliably because it no longer forces a pass. Thank you for the clarification, @matt.